# how to position image in a circle android layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I'm trying to design a rosary app where the beads are individual images so that I can configure each image at will, but I am having trouble positioning them in a relativelayout to make a perfect circle. They're very rigid and angular instead of circular. (see image) What other options do i have?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better option to create a custom view and do the drawing yourself.

If u wanna stick with the viewgroup solution create a custom viewgroup and handle the measuring,layout pass yourself.